# Save screenshots on tvOS

Tags: screenshot, apple-tv, tvos

The question is very simple, but i haven't found an answer.

How can i take a screenshot on tvOS?

In simulator is straightforward, just **File -> Save Screenshot**, but on a real device? 
I already tried some combination of buttons, but nothing happened.

Let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With the Apple TV connected to your development machine via USB.

### Steps

- In **XCode** from the menu **Window** -> **Devices**
- Select the Apple TV on the left representing your device.
- On the device, configure the screen the way you want to capture it.
- Click the **Take Screenshot** button.
- It will save the screenshot to your development Mac

> The new screenshot appears on the desktop.

For reference:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-devices_organizer/articles/capture_screenshots_from_device.html